# removing matching brackets

Tags: parsing, nested

I would like to parse a text like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor \tag{sit} amet, \git{consetetur} sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut \tag{labore \git{et} dolore magna aliquyam
erat, sed} diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
\tag{rebum.}
```

into

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \git{consetetur} sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore \git{et} dolore magna aliquyam
erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum.
```

i.e., remove all the `\tag{...}` environments. They can be *nested* and can *span over multiple lines*.

As learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079453/removing-environments-with-sed), regular expression tools are not suited for the task.

Is there a language or Unix tool that is ideal for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that with perl:

```
perl -0ne 's/\\tag{//g;$i=0;while(/./gs){$i-- if $& eq "{";$i++ if $& eq "}"; if ($i<1){print $&}else{$i=0}}'
```

All the credits should be for [bartus11](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/145336-multiline-parenthesis-matching-e-g-sed-script-latex-doc.html#post_message_302458224)